# Split value of one Textbox into two halves and populate two other Textboxes using wpf,databinding and pure xaml only

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

I have one textbox named txtMain whose max length is 30 and I have two other textboxes named txtName1 and txtName2 each of whose length is 15.

The first 15 characters of txtMain should be populated in txtName1 and the next 15 characters of txtMain should be populated in txtName2.

I can do this by using events from code behind,but i want to use databinding,triggers and pure XAML for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and pure XAML

Not possible to extract substrings and process without code behind because XAML is a markup language which does not have the ability to do direct data manipulation.

> but i want to use databinding

Have three properties which are bound. The change happens when the main changes and it simply notifies its change with the other two. The other two just substring out the needed substrings such as:

```
private string _main;

public string MainString
{
   get { return _main; }
   set {
           _main = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("MainString");
          OnPropertyChanged("FirstPart");
          OnPropertyChanged("SecondPart");
       } 
}

public int Size  { get { return MainString?.Count ?? 0; } }

public string FirstPart { get 
           { return MainString?.Substring(0, Math.Min(15, Size)) ?? string.Empty; } }.

public string SecondPart
{
    get
    {
        if (size > 15) 
            return str.Substring(15, Math.Min(15, (size - 15))).Dump();

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

---

Another way to solve this is to write specific converters which could split out the textual information. But that also is a code behind solution.

Comment: tx OmegaMan.I was doing it via code behind only,but thought maybe someone might have a better idea..:-).ie how to do it using pure xaml only...Anyways tx for the conformation that my requirement needs to be addressed via code behind only..:-).

Comment: @JatinderWalia if you are satisfied with the answer and it resolves the issue, please mark it as the `answer` so others will know of the resolution. :-)